# Creating a View from Different Another View and Calculate Some Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables (`Daily_log` and `Six_months_Log`) the first one(`Daily_log`) consists of daily records of data and the second one (`Six_months_Log`) It consists of data of six-month periods, The first six months show by `1` and the second six months shows by `2`.
However, both of them are the same but For each record in the `[Six_months_Log]` Table, we have many records in `[Daily_log]` Table. So I want to Calculate the average of the records for every six months in `[Daily_log]` Table for each parallel record in `[Six_months_Log]` Table and finally
The result of the average of `[Daily_log].[Value]` is multiplied by `[Six_months_Log].[Value]` of other Table:

> Each row of Table:  `[Daily_log].[Value]` x `[Six_months_Log].[Value]`

In `Daily_log` we have:

`[Code_Type]:`  *602* is Daily code

`[Half]:` `1` is The first six months of the year and `2` is The second six months of the year

`[Location]:` each place has a uniq code

```
=============================| Daily_log |==========================
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| ID    | Location  |    Date    |Code_Type|  Year | Value  | Half |
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| 1200  |  20200    |2015/01/01  | 602     | 2015  | 550    |  1   |
| 1202  |  20200    |2015/01/02  | 602     | 2015  | 680    |  1   |
| 1203  |  20200    |2015/01/03  | 602     | 2015  | 780    |  1   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
| 1420  |  20200    |2015/06/01  | 602     | 2015  | 260    |  2   |
| 1421  |  20200    |2015/06/02  | 602     | 2015  | 790    |  2   |
| 1422  |  20200    |2015/06/03  | 602     | 2015  | 640    |  2   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
| 1420  |  15300    |2017/11/01  | 602     | 2017  | 470    |  2   |
| 1421  |  15300    |2017/11/02  | 602     | 2017  | 990    |  2   |
| 1422  |  15300    |2017/11/03  | 602     | 2017  | 140    |  2   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
```

In `Six_months_Log` we have:

`[Code_Type]:` *402* is Six_months code

`[Half]:` `1` is The first six months of the year and `2` is The second six months of the year

`[Location]:` each place has a uniq code

```
========================| Six_months_Log |==========================
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| ID    | Location  |    Date    |Code_Type|  Year | Value  | Half |
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
| 201   |  20200    |2015/01/01  | 402     | 2015  | 50     |  1   |
| 202   |  20200    |2015/07/01  | 402     | 2015  | 80     |  2   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
| 320   |  20201    |2015/01/01  | 402     | 2015  | 60     |  1   |
| 321   |  20201    |2015/07/01  | 402     | 2015  | 90     |  2   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
| 820   |  15300    |2017/01/01  | 402     | 2017  | 70     |  1   |
| 821   |  15300    |2017/07/01  | 402     | 2017  | 20     |  2   |
| ...   |...        |...         | ...     | ...   | ...    | ...  |
+-------+-----------+------------+---------+-------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Ok, to start, nesting views is a quick way to performance problems. Second, what is the question? How to calculate the average value in 6 month partitions? Can you edit the post and add your current query?

Comment: Desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select sml.*, dl.avg_value, dl.avg_value * sml.value
from six_months_log sml outer apply
     (select avg(dl.value) as avg_value
      from daily_log dl
      where dl.location = sml.location and
            dl.date <= sml.date and
            dl.date > dateadd(month, -6, sml.date)
     ) dl;
```

For performance, you want an index on `daily_log(location, date, value)`.

Comment: Yes, exactly!
Thank you so much, pal.